# Building a comment/post and reply system

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a comment system that has replies which can be tied to a particular comment.

Here is my sample code. I tried joining two tables together to display each reply for different comments.

```
function get_comments() {
    $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM comments, reply");

    $rowCount = $query->rowCount();

    if ($rowCount >= 1) {
        $result = $query->fetchAll();
    }
    else {
        $result = 0;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Where lies the question?

Comment: @Jesse, I've approved your edit, but would tend to discourage code reformatting, since it can sometimes accidentally mask an error in a user's question.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the advice. But, just wondering, how can a correct indentation of a php code mask an user error?

Comment: @Jesse, just by making a mistake. A minor error in editing text usually doesn't matter too much, but even a single wrong keypress in code can add in a syntax error - or can remove the error that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That SQL query doesn't look like it's joining anything.

Since a reply is also a comment, you might be able to have a table structure like:

```
table comments
    id
    in_reply_to_id
    commenter_name
    comment_text
```

The `in_reply_to_id` refers to the `id` of the comment that this comment is in reply to.

Then you can query like:

```
select * from comments where in_reply_to_id = whatever_comment_id
```

to get all of the replies to the comment that has `id` equal to `whatever_comment_id`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way enough code there to fulfill what you require. In short you need a comments and a reply table as you have, the reply table should have a field for Comment_ID, and when you loop through each comment to display, have an inner loop that loops through each comment reply and displays it under the current comment you are iterating through.

Comment: thanks everyone i have been able to solve it, it seems that the fault is with the way i queried the database: